# Specify with Ansible a ufw rule involving 2 network interfaces and the direction of traffic

Tags: ansible, idempotent, ufw

Is there a way to use `ufw` on ansible to specify finely tuned rules that involve 2 network interfaces and the direction of the traffic through them?

The equivalent command is:

```
ufw route allow in on wg0 out on eth0
ufw route allow in on eth0 out on wg0
```

From the docs here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ufw_module.html I can see someone can only specify the network interface once, see their example:

```
- name: Allow incoming access to eth0 from 1.2.3.5 port 5469 to 1.2.3.4 port 5469
  community.general.ufw:
    rule: allow
    interface: eth0
    direction: in
    proto: udp
    src: 1.2.3.5
    from_port: '5469'
    dest: 1.2.3.4
    to_port: '5469'
```

See those parameters `interface` and `direction`. The `dest` field is used with an IP address in the examples but not available in the list of fields for `ufw` or it does not look like someone could use it with a network interface.

I managed to work around the above using `shell`:

```
  - name: Route traffic using network interfaces
    shell: |
      ufw route allow in on wg0 out on eth0
      ufw route allow in on eth0 out on wg0
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
```

However this is not idempotent as I see the task is always executed when I run the playbook multiple times.

As an alternative solution how can I make the above task idempotent if the Ansible `ufw` does not allow these complex rules to be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

It is now supported by options "interface_in" "interface_out".

See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ufw_module.html#parameter-interface_in

Comment: That's really helpful, can you please provide also a brief example of the YAML code? I would like to accept this answer. Thanks.